# DIV won't align, gets pushed down below content

Tags: html, css

I've built this site over at http://edge.directiongroup.co.uk/ and on the homepage you can see the right div class '.sidebar' is being pushed down somehow.

On another page http://edge.directiongroup.co.uk/content-marketing/ there isn't a problem.

It seems to be caused by #edge_header on the homepage but I can't figure out what I need to change to make the right .sidebar div be correctly positioned on both pages.

The CSS for #edge_header which seems to be causing the problem is here:-

```
#edge_header {
background: url("images/edge_header.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom rgb(255, 255, 255);
width: 618px;
height: 318px;
float: left;
}
```

Stack overflow is usually last resort to through a question over to you guys for this, can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: if you make your width smaller does that fix the problem?  Can you also post the code for the sidebar?

Comment: It will float left only if there is space, your example requires 618px of space on the left, which is not being used by another element, even white space. Have you tried changing the order of the html elements? Using browser tools to check the space used of its neighbors? The problem is likely related to a sibling. Can you post the siblings css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to place `.sidebar` before `.edge_header` in your HTML, e.g.

http://linenwoods.com/images/capture.png

Comment: I just did exactly the same. Explanation: Since your sidebar is floating right and the other divs float left this isn't an issue, unless you want sidebar to come last in the source code, in which case wrapping the header and content inside another div that floats will allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has to do with the way the floating is set up - the `#edge_header` div that's pushing the sidebar down (I set it to display: none and the problem goes away). Try putting the #edge-header into the main content div?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have this `<div>` structure in place in your core content:

```
<div class="edge_header"></div>
<div class="main_content"></div>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

The issue is `edge_header` is taking precedent over `sidebar` in the DOM.  So it is properl floating, but it is floating after `edge_header` has rendered.

This kind of alignment issues with floats is common & maddening. Everyone has different CSS layout techniques. To me, the best solution would be to create two wrapper `<div>` elements & nest the `<div>` elements in there. One for the main area. And one for the sidebar.  I’m naming them `main_wrapper` and `sidebar_wrapper` for this example. So your structure would be more like this:

```
<div class="main_wrapper">
  <div class="edge_header"></div>
  <div class="main_content"></div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Just have those float similarly to your other elements. And in this way, the content in `main_wrapper` will be isolated from the content in `sidebar_wrapper`.

The reason I prefer this is it keeps the content semantically flowing in a way that is readable if/when you debug it. And in my experience, this kind of wrapping `<div>` technique works well as far as cross browser/platform compatibility issues go.